# Munich Airport to Manching

Tags: public-transport, germany, airport-transfer, transportation, munich

I want to go from MUC to Manching, but it seems that gmaps couldn't find a transit (train, bus, etc.).

Does anyone knows a way to go there (it seems that Uber is not an option, and I do not know how much a taxi will cost)?

PS: I won't be in hurry.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best source for public transport in Germany is [reiseauskunft.bahn.de](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de). You can switch the language to English by clicking on the word "Deutschland" at the top and selecting "Germany" instead. I just tried, there are options. Essentially, you have to take the S-Bahn to Munich central, take a train to Ingolstadt and then a bus to Manching; the total travel time is 2-2.5 hours and the price is 25-35 Euro.

According to taxi-rechner.de, a taxi would cost approximately 106 Euros. I guess that's not worth it if you're not in a hurry...

Comment: For target, you set "Manching Ost", right?

Comment: Yes I did. But I think you can also enter an address if you don't know the best stop

Comment: You can also simply add `Country=USA` to the URL to change it for everyone: [This should work](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/en?country=USA&protocol=https:).

Comment: S-Bahn 11.60 + Train 19.40 + Bus16 2.90 = 32.90 Euros in total. Begun from Munich Airport at 15.00, arrived at Landgasthof Euringer at 19.00, but was not hurrying at all in the way (for example, I could have run and catch the S-Bahn-result: had to wait 15 mins). Thanks Sabine (sent from my hotel room). You make Internet a better place. =)

Comment: When set to the USA version you are a bit restricted in what you can buy. Using the UK or general 'Europe English' version is less restricted.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of taking the train from Munich central to Ingolstadt, you can also take a bus from the airport straight to the Ingolstadt central bus station. This bus costs between 15,50 and 23 euros (depending on whether you buy a return ticket as well and whether you book in advance) and leaves every hour. See https://www.invg.de/fahrplan_airport_express for the schedule.

Comment: The bus is 15€ for kids (15 y/o or younger) and 23€ for adults

Comment: Train costs 19.40, but a good alternative too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Manching doesn't have a station and the regional bus operator (INVG) isn't in Google Maps. The best way is to take the Airport Express from either Terminal 1 or 2 to Ingolstadt Central Station (Hauptbahnhof). This is rather close to the town of Manching and you can take one of the regional buses. There's an information desk at the station.

Traveling from Munich airport to Manching via Munich city would cost too much time.

Comment: Thank you Aliger for your answer. So you agree with Sabine's answer, right?

Comment: I more agree with Ingolstadter to take the bus. Sabine's answer leads you via Munich city centre and this costs time and money.

Answer (score 0):

Except from [reiseauskunft.bahn.de](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/dn?protocol=https:) which was posted above, the bus site was also helpful: [shop.flixbus.de](https://shop.flixbus.de/). It found me a nice route to Ulm from the airport in another journey, Google maps failed to find.